# Map a table created by hibernate in other table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

i am working on Spring Data JPA with Hibernate. I want to create a mapping table using hibernate automatically and want to retrieve the values based on the id's of each individual tables.

CustomerEntity.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "customers")
@Entity
public class CustomerEntity  {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "customerId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID customerId;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "itemId", nullable = false)
private Set<ItemEntity> itemEntities;



   //More customer fields

}
```

ItemEntity.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "items")
@Entity
public class ItemEntity  {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "itemId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID itemId;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "itemEntities")
private List<CustomerEntity> customerEntities;
   //More item fields
}
```

Now hibernate created a mapping table with manyToMany for these two based on the id's

something like below:

MappingTable:

```
customerId // primary key from customer table

itemId // primary key from item table
```

As hibernate creates this table on the fly and i dont have the details of this table. Now i want to create a map this table from another table like below:

OrderEntity.Java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "items")
@Entity
public class OrderEntity  {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "itemId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID orderId;

//How can i map this table to the above mapping table with all two columns?

}
```

Any help is appreciated.TIA

Comment: it is simple you create manytoone relation inside ItemEntity  and you use order_id

Comment: @MohdAlomar can you please show me an example? I am really confused and i want to map order table with both item and customer. Any example would be helpful here please. Thnaks

Comment: what is the relation between OrderEntity  and CustomerEntitiy, and OrderEntity  and ItemEntity. And are you sure that customer have many item? not orders? and are you sure that item belong to many customers at same time !

Comment: Yes. Typically i am trying to give an example for my case. Yes you are correct. @MohdAlomar

Comment: can you give and example of OrderEntity  and it is relation between CustomerEntitiy and ItemEntity so I can map it for you.

Comment: if you want many to many between three entities see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918513/hibernate-annotatoin-how-to-join-three-tables-with-many-to-many-relationship 

but I think your design is wrong if you are building a ordinary order object .